# Symmetric tensor decomposition

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensor

Let $T$ be an order-$k$, rank-$m$ symmetric tensor, that is, $T=\sum_{j=1}^m v_j\otimes v_j \otimes \cdots \otimes v_j$, where the Segre outer product is taken $k$ times, with $v_j\in\mathbb{R}^d$ for all $j$. That is to say, for every $i_1,\dots,i_k\in\{1,2,\dots,d\}$, it holds that, $T_{i_1,\dots,i_k}=\sum_{j=1}^m v_{ji_1}v_{ji_2}\cdots v_{ji_k}$.

My question is as follows.

1) Given a $T$, that is known to be symmetric and order $k$, can such a decomposition be found, with the same rank?

2) Assume, the same rank condition is removed. Can such a decomposition be found? That is, are there $v_1',\dots,v_M'\in\mathbb{R}^d$, such that, $\sum_{j=1}^M v_i'\otimes v_i' \otimes \cdots \otimes v_i'$ where the outer product is $k$ times can be found?

3) How about uniqueness? Under what conditions on $m$ and $d$, we can say the recovery is unique?

Comment: These are very complicated questions and in general not much is known.  Did you google the term ?  wikipedia does provide some good starting points for research including J.M. Landsburg's book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A recent introduction is [Carlini, et al, *Four lectures on secant varieties*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3213518). Adam mentioned [Landsberg, *Tensors: Geometry and Applications*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2865915).

In brief:

1(a). If $T$ is a symmetric tensor of tensor rank $m$, does $T$ have a symmetric decomposition with $m$ terms?

Probably not. If $T$ is symmetric and has rank $m$, it may not be the case that there exists a symmetric decomposition with $m$ terms. In the lingo, the symmetric rank of a symmetric tensor may not be equal to the rank; this is known to happen over $\mathbb{C}$, and expected (at least by me) to also happen over $\mathbb{R}$. See [Waring rank vs tensor rank of symmetric tensors?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284079/waring-rank-vs-tensor-rank-of-symmetric-tensors), https://mathoverflow.net/a/322467/88133.

1(b). Suppose that $T$ is a symmetric tensor with both tensor rank and symmetric tensor rank equal to $m$. In this case, is it possible to find, in some sense, a symmetric decomposition with $m$ terms? That is, is there some algorithm or numerical method to find an $m$ term symmetric decomposition?

Yes and no. There are algorithms and methods. First of all, there is simple brute force: just write $T = v_1^{\otimes k} + \dotsb + v_m^{\otimes k}$, and solve for the entries of the $v_i$, using methods such as Gröbner bases. Certainly this is quite inefficient, but it counts as a method. There are better methods. See for example [Brachat, et al, *Symmetric tensor decomposition*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2736103). There are quite a few more recent papers that refer to that one. You can use MathSciNet to find them. Some of them are iterative and numerical, others are exact (if the tensor $T$ was given exactly).

2. Can some symmetric decomposition be found?

Yes, a symmetric decomposition can be found, by polarization identities. I will describe a wildly non-minimal symmetric decomposition. Finding a *minimal* symmetric decomposition is a huge problem---see the algorithms discussed above; and even in the "theoretical" approach, it's still difficult.

The polarization identities, or at least one version, are the identities
$$
  v_1 \cdot \dotsm \cdot v_k
  = \frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \sum \pm (v_1 \pm \dotsb \pm v_k)^{\otimes k},
$$
where $\cdot$ is the symmetric tensor product (sum over all permutations),
the sum is taken over all $2^{k-1}$ choices of $\pm$ coefficients inside the parentheses, and the coefficient in front of the parentheses is the product of the ones inside. For example,
$$
  v_1 \cdot v_2 = v_1 \otimes v_2 + v_2 \otimes v_1 = \frac{1}{2}((v_1+v_2)^{\otimes 2} - (v_1 - v_2)^{\otimes 2}),
$$
and
$$
\begin{split}  v_1 \cdot v_2 \cdot v_3
  &= v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_3 + v_1 \otimes v_3 \otimes v_2 + \dotsb + v_3 \otimes v_2 \otimes v_1 \\
  &= \frac{1}{4}((v_1+v_2+v_3)^{\otimes 3}-(v_1+v_2-v_3)^{\otimes 3}-(v_1-v_2+v_3)^{\otimes 3} \\
  &\qquad \qquad +(v_1-v_2-v_3)^{\otimes 3}). \\
\end{split}
$$
These hold for *all* $v_i$, even if they are linearly dependent, or even equal (although if $v_1=v_2$, say, then terms like $(v_1-v_2+\dotsb)$ will certainly simplify). So every symmetric tensor can be decomposed "term by term". This is explicit.

Even for a single term (symmetric product) the above decomposition is usually not minimal. A minimal decomposition over $\mathbb{C}$ is described in [Buczynska, et al, *Waring decompositions of monomials*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3017012). But that's just for monomials; beyond that, practically everything is open. Even for binomials, nobody knows the answer. Over $\mathbb{R}$, even the monomial case is open, see [Carlini, et al, *On the real rank of monomials*](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3648510). As Adam said in the comments, these are very complicated questions and not much is known!

On MathOverflow, see [Efficient way to express a symmetric tensor in terms of rank one elements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321570/efficient-way-to-express-a-symmetric-tensor-in-terms-of-rank-one-elements); [Generalization of the Polarisation Formula for Symmetric Bilinear Forms to Symmetric multilinear Forms](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98714/generalization-of-the-polarisation-formula-for-symmetric-bilinear-forms-to-symme); [polarization formula for homogeneous polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61884/polarization-formula-for-homogeneous-polynomials/61891#61891); and more, if you search (in fact, if you browse through my answers, I think a lot of them are on this topic).

3. How about uniqueness?

A (symmetric) tensor is called **identifiable** if it has a unique shortest decomposition (uniqueness up to permuting terms and rescaling factors in terms). [Mella](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2238925) and [Galuppi-Mella](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06895) have recently solved the problem of identifiability of general symmetric tensors. There are other results, e.g., identifiability of "most" tensors of less than generic rank, or [identifiability over the reals versus identifiability over the complex numbers](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3781595). There is a well-known **Kruskal's criterion** for identifiability (which you can find by searching).

Comment: Zach, thanks for reply. Few notes:

1) I assume $T$ to be of form $T=\sum_{j=1}^n v_j\otimes \cdots\otimes v_j$. Then, say, I'm asking the reverse question, whether $T$ can be decomposed (I do know that $T$ is of that particular form). Mine is more on the algorithmic front.

I also did not understand your answer to 2nd part. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @kawa: updated answer, I hope it helps!